# Getting SQLite database from emulator (data/data/package_name/databases) to local drive

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I would like to edit my app's DB using the SQLite Browser.  I'm able to edit the DB using the adb shell (sqlite3), but I would rather edit it using a GUI rather than a command line.  How do I get the DB from the emulator to a local drive?  As of now I've tried:

1) using the adb pull command to pull the database from the emulator to my local drive.

adb pull data/data/com.myapps.quiz c:/

This command executes correctly, but I'm not able to find the file or directory in the local drive I specified.

2)  Used the DDMS Perspective to locate the file in the File Explorer, but every time I get into the data/data directory, I only see directories called "con".  I even tried pulling the entire data/data directory, but I can't find the name of the package (com.myapps.quiz) where the database is stored.

What am I missing here?  Any help you could provide would be most helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Your database is secure to your package so you cannot get this directly.

I have a work around for this.

What I do is go to shell and run-as my package and copy the database to sdcard using cat

```
adb shell
run-as your.package.name
cd databases
cat your_database.db > /mnt/sdcard/your_database.db
```

And I pull the file from the sdcard using File Explorer

Comment: Thanks.  This looks promising, but now I'm running into permission problems.  It says "Permission denied."  Is there anyway I can edit the permission of the mnt/sdcard directory?

Comment: I am not sure but i think your package does not have a write Permission on SDCard defined in Manifest. That's the reason it shows Permission denied. Try to give android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE use-permission in your manifest.

Comment: Ok I put that in the Manifest file, but to no avail :-(.  I'm sure it's something really simple.  If you have another suggestions, that would be great.  I think the the permissions could be with the DB file and I tried using chmod to change the permissions, but again denied.  Why can't I get access to this DB?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're connecting to the emulator instance in DDMS, and not an actual device? I have always been able to push and pull sqlite databases from the

```
 data/data/com.my.package/databases/mydb.sqlite
```

directory, and I can't think of any setting that would override that. An alternative would be to root an actual phone and then you will be able to move anything from the phone to your computer.

Comment: I go to the DDMS view in Eclipse while the program that accesses the DB is running.  Am I connecting to the emulator instance in DDMS?  I know this is strange to me.  When I go to the data/data directory, I only see folder called "con".  Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried connecting via adb in the shell. I.e start an emulator incidence independently of the program, then run adb -devices. You should get something back like "emulator-5554". If not then you have a wider problem and I would reinstall eclipse and all android tools and sdks. If you do get something back then try adb -e shell ls /data/data That will list the directories. Post back what output you get. Other info available at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html